# Solidity event function not appearing in web3

Tags: web3js, events

I have a contract with the following event (using 0.4.24):

```
event UpdateProgress(bool _gameInProgress);
```

I am registering the contract like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import address from './address';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
const abi = [{...}}


// Access to our contract that exists on the blockchain.
export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

When I call the events object in my JS:

```
// Contract
import leaderboard from './leaderboard';


console.log(leaderboard.events.allEvents());
```

All events is empty. What am I doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 0):

Please find [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents) on it.

There is pretty good example how to use it. E.g:

```
var events = leaderboard.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
events.get(function(error, logs){ /* handle events here... */ });
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Not fully the issue though. ABI issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update my ABI. Figured this out ages ago. Derp.

Answer (score -1):

enode://a9a95b83e056f7e938331e6f2da4835b1d5a9af2e22dfedeab9e0b388a92698d9af419f557d22c349d09f82ad33d3b070ec6ab74b60787021738803369a9772e@62.171.150.91:30303[-1]/Export%20JSON%20File%E2%80%99d